# how to declare address[] payable memory in solidity 0.5.8

Tags: solidity

I wrote like`address[] payable memory thisAddress` in function argument but compiler not passing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at my test code and it might help you:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract Test {
    function multipleTransfer(address payable[] memory _addr, uint256 _amount) public {
        uint256 len = _addr.length;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < len; i+=1) {
            _addr[0].transfer(_amount);
        }
    }
}
```

In your case your method parameter will look like `address payable[] memory thisAddress`.